# How to Access the Source name in DragOver

Tags: delphi

I cannot figure out how to access the name of the Source TObject being dragged over a panel.

```
procedure TfrmBodyPlan.pnlStepsDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
```

I know that the object is a TAdvShape.

Answer (score 3):

Just cast the object :

```
if Sender is TComponent then
  LName := TComponent(Sender).Name;
```